# OpenSSL public key for Firefox extension signing

Tags: firefox, openssl, firefox-addon

I'm trying to bring back an old extension I made for Firefox 1.5 written in JavaScript. One of the changes introduced in Firefox 3.0 was the need for extension updates secured via either HTTPS or PKI. Since I can't use an SSL solution on my website, I need to use the PKI solution.

So, first up is generating the private and public keys. I was able to create CA and client (code signing) certificates using OpenSSL by following [this guide](http://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/12/30/howto-make-your-own-cert-with-openssl/). So, how I have two key and certificate pairs: `ca.crt`, `ca.key`, `code.crt` and `code.key`.

Now, I have to put the public key into the `install.rdf`'s `<em:updateKey>` field. I did this with the command `openssl -in code.key -outform DER -pubout` and copied the resulting output (sans the ^-----.* lines) into my `install.rdf`. Now, the public key generated in this way is base64-encoded and ends with a couple equals signs. I haven't seen any examples that actually have these trailing characters. Is that OK, or did I pass the wrong options to OpenSSL?

Aside from this, using `uhura` to sign my `update.rdf` seems fairly straight-forward, but again there are no trailing =='s, which seems odd from the output I got via the OpenSSL command above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Trailing "=" is just a padding char in [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. And you don't need a CA, but that shouldn't really matter. Did you actually try if it works? If you did, and it doesn't, then what are the errors?

Comment: I am aware that the '='s are padding for the base64 encoding. But in two keys that I generated in this manner, they both produced the padding at the end instead of ending cleanly like in every example I've seen and the signatures produced by uhura. I don't really have a means to test this at the moment, which is why I posed it as a question.

Comment: Maybe the example keys did not need padding (`len(key) % 3 == 0`), while your key does? Just try it once you find time, and report back. Right now it is too much time to reproduce and *debug* something that might not be broken in the first place...

Comment: "Any help would be greatly appreciated..." - what, exactly, do you need help with? You don't seem to have a problem, and you did not ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working using a localhost webserver configuration. The OpenSSL command is the correct one to use in this case and the trailing padding is a coincidence, but it works when fetching updates.